# How could I close tqdm_gui?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tqdm

I'm new to parallel processing. In my software I want to do some parser jobs parallel to speed up and I want to inform the user that the parsing jobs are still running. I found tqdm to do this job and I'm having now the problem to close the figure from tqdm_gui.

Looking around I found this post from  Dan Shiebler:
http://danshiebler.com/2016-09-14-parallel-progress-bar/

I change this code a little bit to use it with the GUI from tqdm. See the code snippet below.

If I call the parallel_process_gui again, there is still an (old) figure behind the (new) one. How could I close this, both or all figures?

What I have already tried is to change the leave flag from True to False

```
kwargs = {
            'total': len(futures),
            'unit': 'it',
            'unit_scale': True,
            'leave': True,
            'desc': desc
        }
```

and try to close the figure with

```
tqdm.tqdm_gui.close()
```

with no luck

The code snippet:

```
import tqdm
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import sleep

def parallel_process_gui(array,
                         function,
                         n_jobs=16,
                         desc='process',
                         use_kwargs=False,
                         front_num=3):
    """
        A parallel version of the map function with a progress bar.

        http://danshiebler.com/2016-09-14-parallel-progress-bar/

        Args:
            array (array-like): An array to iterate over.
            function (function): A python function to apply to the elements of array
            n_jobs (int, default=16): The number of cores to use
            use_kwargs (boolean, default=False): Whether to consider the elements
            of array as dictionaries of keyword arguments to function
            front_num (int, default=3): The number of iterations to run serially
            before kicking off the parallel job. Useful for catching bugs

        Returns:
            [function(array[0]), function(array[1]), ...]
    """
    # We run the first few iterations serially to catch bugs
    if front_num > 0:
        front = [function(**a) if use_kwargs else function(a)
                 for a in array[:front_num]]
    else:
        front = []
    # If we set n_jobs to 1, just run a list comprehension. This is useful for
    # benchmarking and debugging.
    if n_jobs == 1:
        return front + [function(**a) if use_kwargs else function(a)
                        for a in tqdm.tqdm_gui(array[front_num:])]
    # Assemble the workers
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_jobs) as pool:
        # Pass the elements of array into function
        if use_kwargs:
            futures = [pool.submit(function, **a) for a in array[front_num:]]
        else:
            futures = [pool.submit(function, a) for a in array[front_num:]]
        kwargs = {
            'total': len(futures),
            'unit': 'it',
            'unit_scale': True,
            'leave': True,
            'desc': desc
        }
        # Print out the progress as tasks complete
        for f in tqdm.tqdm_gui(as_completed(futures), **kwargs):
            pass

    out = []
    # Get the results from the futures.
    for i, future in tqdm.tqdm_gui(enumerate(futures)):
        try:
            out.append(future.result())
        except Exception as e:
            out.append(e)

    return front + out


def get_big_number(i, how_many):
    '''
    only for tests. Generates a big number
    :param i: factor
    :param how_many: iterations of additions
    '''
    return sum([100000 * 100000 * i for i in range(how_many)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    build an array (arr) of dicts. Each dict has all parameters (i, how_many)
    of function (get_big_number) for parallel processing. in this example
    1000 processes are started
    '''
    arr = [{'i': i, 'how_many': 100000 if i % 2 else 220000}
           for i in range(10)]
    # show 1st 10 dicts
    for i in range(10):
        print (i, " ", arr[i])

    list_of_big = parallel_process_gui(
        arr,
        get_big_number,
        desc="progress 1",
        front_num=0,
        use_kwargs=True)

    arr = [{'i': i, 'how_many': 100000 if i % 2 else 220000}
           for i in range(1000)]

    #run it again, now there is one (old) window in background of 
    #a new progressbar 
    list_of_big = parallel_process_gui(
        arr,
        get_big_number,
        desc="progress 2",
        front_num=0,
        use_kwargs=True)

    # show 1st 10 results
    for i in range(10):
        print (i, " ", list_of_big[i])

    # show last 10 results
    for i in range(990, 1000):
        print (i, " ", list_of_big[i])

    sleep(10)
```

I know that the tqdm_gui is still experimental/alpha, but I expect that the progressbar is closed after doing the parsing jobs.

Any help would appreciated.

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

I found my bug.

Inside the parallel_process_gui at the end I change the getting results from

```
    # Get the results from the futures.
    for i, future in tqdm.tqdm_gui(enumerate(futures)):
        try:
            out.append(future.result())
        except Exception as e:
            out.append(e)
```

to

```
    # Get the results from the futures.
    for i, future in enumerate(futures):
        try:
            out.append(future.result())
        except Exception as e:
            out.append(e)
```

This works! Iterate the results with

```
tqdm.tqdm_gui(enumerate(futures))
```

opens the unwanted figure.

Thomas